# How to properly logout from Teams BotFramework OauthPrompt?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a c# Teams bot that uses multiple Generic Oauth2 providers.
As an example I have used this sample https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth

Also I have added Generic OAuth2 to Bot Registration in Azure. Everything works fine with single Oauth provider.

User after logout process must be able to authenticate to another oauth2 provider.
But I'm faced with problem that OauthPrompt caches previous credentials, and I don't know how to clear this cache and properly sign out user

I've already tried different approaches to sign out user:

- Using UserTokenClient

```
var userTokenClient = innerDc.Context.TurnState.Get<UserTokenClient>();
await userTokenClient.SignOutUserAsync(innerDc.Context.Activity.From.Id, connectionName,
                            innerDc.Context.Activity.ChannelId, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

- Using OauthPrompt dialog

```
var oauth = (OAuthPrompt)Dialogs.Find(nameof(OAuthPrompt));
if (oauth != null)
{
    await oauth.SignOutUserAsync(innerDc.Context, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

--Using BotFrameworkAdapter

```
await botAdapter.SignOutUserAsync(innerDc.Context, connectionName, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Please help

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft thanks for reply. But I found a problem.
See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a problem.
Bot was registered as a Singleton in services (services.AddSingleton <..>), аnd OauthPrompt dialog was added in waterfall step and didn't disposed.
I have created different OauthPrompts for each Generic OAuth and added to dialog throught dialog constructor. And based user prompt choosed the right OauthPrompt

```
            AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt("1",
                new OAuthPromptSettings
                {
                    ConnectionName = "1",
                    Text = "Please Sign In",
                    Title = "Sign In",
                    Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
                }));
            AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt("2",
                new OAuthPromptSettings
                {
                    ConnectionName = "2",
                    Text = "Please Sign In",
                    Title = "Sign In",
                    Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
                }));
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved or are you still looking for any help?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Issue is resolved, thanks